# Sending email with Amazon SES, asynchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, smtp, amazon-ses

When sending email with Amazon SES, there are two main options. **SMTP interface** and **SES API**.

I have a set of email messages needed to be sent to various recipients. I need to iterate through this set of messages and send via Amazon SES. 
My question is, will the process be synchronous (current email has to wait until the last one is completed) or not.

I'm expecting a asynchronous method and I wouldn't mind to use either SMTP interface or SES API.

I went through the documentation and I couldn't find an answer to this.

Comment: Define "asynchronous" in this context.  You don't have to wait for SES to *deliver* the message -- you get back a response when the service accepts your message -- but you have to wait for the API request or SMTP transaction to complete, in order to know whether it succeeded.  Not quite sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're saying when using SES API, SendEmail(SendEmailRequest) method returns the 'SendEmailResponse' right after the message is accepted and queued, but not after it delivered right?

Comment: You can make requests to the REST API, in which case you should use whatever async tool you're using to make that request asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending email through AWS SES is asynchronous, which means emails will deliver asynchronously by SES, but you have to wait until the the email request has been queued to know whether the request to send email has been completed. If you want that to be asynchronous, you can put it in background tasks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/ses-example-send-email.html

Comment: So in this example we're just not checking for a result. We're just grabbing a promise and moving on ...